# Swing UI Delay adding and removing elements

Tags: swing, swingutilities, metawidget

I have a form stored in both the inputWidget and the outputWidget. The buttons addInput and addOutput will show two different forms in the secondaryInOutPanel.

However there is a significant delay when moving between the form by clicking the buttons. In fact it changes when I attempting to click on the form. And there is still some visible drawings from the pervious form.

I tried using SwingUtilities but that caused the delay to be worst.

```
    secondaryInOutPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    secondaryInOutPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200,400));     

    JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
    outinPanel.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JButton addInput = new JButton("Add Input");
    btnPanel.add(addInput);
    addInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            secondaryInOutPanel.removeAll();                                
            secondaryInOutPanel.add(inputWidget, BorderLayout.NORTH);               
            JButton addBtn = new JButton("Save Input");
            secondaryInOutPanel.add(addBtn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            addBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                      
                }                   
            });
        }
    });

    JButton addOutput = new JButton("Add Output");
    btnPanel.add(addOutput);
    addOutput.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            secondaryInOutPanel.removeAll();                            
            secondaryInOutPanel.add(outputWidget, BorderLayout.NORTH);              
            JButton addBtn = new JButton("Save Output");
            secondaryInOutPanel.add(addBtn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            addBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                      
                }                   
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better design is to use a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to hold your input and output panels. Then you can just swap panels as required. The CardLayout will then manage the revalidating and repainting of the panel for you.

Comment: What is the advantage of using the CardLayout as opposed to the repaint method described above?

Comment: As I already mentioned the layout does all the work of swapping panels and he panel is sized based on the size of all the panels.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a call to `revalidate()` and or `repaint()` on the `secondaryInOutPanel` after you make changes.

Comment: +1, for the general rule to revalidate() and repaint() when adding/removing components from a visible GUI. However, when swapping entire panels (ie, whenever I see the usage of `removeAll()` method) there is generally a better design.